# Date conversion in Mongo Db

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

I am having trouble converting "7/26/2020 18:34:25" into any date format from which Mongo can run aggregate operation.

The date in the Mongo is stored as string.
I have tried "$toDate", "$convert" and "$dateToString".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use [$dateFromString](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/dateFromString/)

```
$project: {
      date: {
         $dateFromString: {
            dateString: '$dateFieldName',
            format: '%m/%d/%Y %H:%M:%S'
         }
      }
   }
```

[playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/UOODYW3vNm0)

Answer (score 0):

Try using Moment Library for converting you date
In your case this code can help you:

```
moment('7/26/2020 18:34:25').toDate();
```

You can test this code on browser side on this page
[enter link description here](https://momentjs.com/)

Comment: Using `moment()` inside an aggregation-pipeline is not possible  (e. g. `$project: { date: moment('$dateFieldName').toDate() }` does not work) You you use `moment()` mainly to specify your queries.